# Python - Image Matching from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to match a human's photo with same human's different photo and trying to show "They are same human" in the result.

Normally, I can do this with scanning two .jpg file but I want to do scan photos from their URLs.

I found a working code for this, but it works so badly.

```
from image_match.goldberg import ImageSignature
gis = ImageSignature()
a = gis.generate_signature('https://cdn.radyofenomen.com/u/img/c/s/h/shakira-1494589060.jpg')
b = gis.generate_signature('https://cdn.radyofenomen.com/u/img/c/s/h/shakira-1487933419.jpg')
gis.normalized_distance(a, b)
print(gis.normalized_distance(a, b))
```

Can you show some good examples or good solutions for me?

Comment: You should probably just download the .jpg images from the URLs and then use the same code you did before with scanning images. It shouldn't work any differently logic wise after you download the files. What exactly do you mean by "works so badly"? Please be more specific as to why your current code is having issues.

Comment: I mean it for; I used this [link](https://image-match.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signatures.html) and it says "Normalized distances of less than 0.40 are very likely matches". In this code, I'm using Shakira's two different photos and rsult is 0.70, it should be less than 0.40

Comment: And if you download those images locally and run your same code you had before do you get the expected result of `< 0.4`? You are making it seem like an issue with your expectations for the algorithm instead of the issue of loading data from the URL.

Comment: I have tried the code above with ```a = gis.generate_signature('/newimages/s1.jpg')``` line and same with ```b``` and result is same (0.70). My other code only shows "matched" result, not a percentage and I tried it and it shows "matched" result. So I think in the code above there is something weird. So as I understand that there is no solution without downloading the pictures?